# What does "upgrade to 18.04" mean?

Tags: upgrade

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on an Asus K53E laptop with 8 GB RAM. I check for updates to the software daily. If there are no updates, it asks me if I want to upgrade? What does upgrade exactly mean? Will my personal files still be there? Will it wipe EVERYTHING and give me a completely new installation of Ubuntu? Or will it allow me to keep my files and applications, and merely upgrade the OS?

When I upgrade my Mac or Windows machines, my personal files remain available after the upgrade. Does Ubuntu do the same, or are there completely different "rules"?

Comment: Ubuntu developers work hard to prevent upgrades from breaking, from deleting data, and from causing other problems. However, they have never tested it on your specific hardware, with your specific customization (if any), so there is always a possibility of destruction and loss. In 13 years of using Ubuntu, I've never had a release-upgrade go bad on me...but I am *always* prepared with a LiveUSB installer and 100% data backup before I begin. It rains hardest on folks who neglected to prepare by bringing an umbrellas.

Answer (score 2):

**What does “dist-upgrade” mean?**

It upgrades current OS and installed programs
The process does not affect personal data stored in `/home` folder
The process will not upgrade the OS version, will not wipe data or settings
It is safe to run it
As you can guess, a backup of personal files is not specially required before an `sudo apt dist-upgrade` but recommended for general use.

From [apt-get manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/apt-get.8):

```
dist-upgrade
   dist-upgrade in addition to performing the function of upgrade,
   also intelligently handles changing dependencies with new versions
   of packages; apt-get has a "smart" conflict resolution system, and
   it will attempt to upgrade the most important packages at the
   expense of less important ones if necessary. So, dist-upgrade
   command may remove some packages. The /etc/apt/sources.list file
   contains a list of locations from which to retrieve desired package
   files. See also apt_preferences(5) for a mechanism for overriding
   the general settings for individual packages.
```

Comment: See my comment to the question. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

## Backup! Backup! Backup!

Backup your personal data. Bad things can happen any day. And especially on the day you try something on your computer you have never done before.

## It will keep your files and applications, and merely upgrade the OS

It will also keep your personal settings and wallpaper. This means if you have been using a different theme, wallpaper etc. to make the desktop your own, the upgrade to a new version of Ubuntu will try to keep as much of those personal modifications as possible. Since upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 is a move from Unity to Gnome Shell, some personal changes may be incompatible and can't be preserved in the Gnome Shell.

All the applications you installed from the Ubuntu Software application or using the `apt` command should work. There are a few exceptions such as a software compiled by you, or installed from a PPA may not work until those are updated to work with the new version of the OS.

## What is upgraded?

The OS.

All (most) of the default applications that came built into Ubuntu, such as the LibreOffice suite.

## There is one "Rule"

Backup your personal data.

How this helps