# Online Upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, upgrade

My question is about upgrading online from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS. One of the responses said that it will NOT upgrade the version, which is exactly what I want to do.

Again, but a it more clearly, will an online upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS remove my personal info and completely overwrite my HD, or will it leave personal info and other installed application programs intact? I understand the basics to backup, but it's not part of my question.

Comment: > upgrading online <  What do you mean by 'upgrading online'?  You *can* do an in-place upgrade while the system is running but you will need to make sure you have a backup of your data in case the upgrade fails.  An in-place upgrade won't replace your data, but it has a chance that it will just outright fail to upgrade properly and then you're left with a broken system and have to do a fresh install and restore from backups anyways.

Comment: If you do a release upgrade, your personal files will be kept. But I don't recommend doing it. I never could smoothly upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 because there are too many changes with unity -> gnome. If you are asking about `apt apgrade`, it won't upgrade to another release.

Comment: This question looks like you are seeking clarification of a previous question. Perhaps [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164867/), or perhaps not. Generally, it's better to improve the wording of your previous question so that future users don't get confused, too.

Comment: Please do not ask the same question again and again. Possible duplicate of [What does "upgrade to 18.04" mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164867/what-does-upgrade-to-18-04-mean)